# выборка из двух таблиц mysql по user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

есть две таблицы users и messages.в users есть столбцы name и id_user.в таблице messages есть text, date и user_id.Задача сделать вывод text и date(из messages) и по user_id выбрать из таблицы users поле name.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен обычный JOIN:

```
SELECT M.text, M.date, U.name
FROM messages M
  JOIN users U ON M.user_id = U.id_user
```